# Pass parameters to Pimple->container->factory

Tags: php, pimple

So I basically want to do this:

```
$this->container['Menu_builder'] = $this->container->factory(function ($c) {
    return new Menu_builder($parameter_1, $parameter_2);
});
```

Where `$parameter_1` and `$parameter_2` are passed in from the call, like this:

```
$menu_builder = $this->container['Menu_builder']('account', 'reset_password');
```

I know the above syntax is incorrect, but I want to pass these strings into the call to `$this->container->factory`.

Is this possible?

For example, if I wanted to instantiate the Menu_builder from various controller functions with different parameters for each controller function.

Comment: So your problem is, that `$parameter_1`/`_2` are out of scope in your anonymous function ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, so how do you pass them in? Hopefully I havent found the one use case of Pimple that you cant do!

Comment: Well you already have your answer in your comment ^ :) `use`, e.g. `function ($c)use($parameter_1, $parameter_2){`

Comment: Any chance you could give me an example, as I cant seem to pass the vars into the closure for some reason?

Comment: I think this should work for you: http://3v4l.org/bZRcq

Comment: So where are we with the question? Did my example ^ helped?

Comment: This might be of help: https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/issues/13#issuecomment-3409414

Comment: @Rizier123 Yeah that worked like a charm! If you make an answer out of your comment Ill accept it :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can use [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to pass your variables to the anonymous functions, e.g.

```
//your parameters needs to be defined here:
$parameter_1 = "XY";
$parameter_2 = 42;

$this->container['Menu_builder'] = $this->container->factory(function ($c)use($parameter_1, $parameter_2) {
                                                                        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
    return new Menu_builder($parameter_1, $parameter_2);
});
```

Comment: And when defined in a service provider?
I think parameters are meant to be passed by defining a container value - ie $container['param1'] = 'some value'.    The anonymous function can then access via $container['param1']

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, you can also include an anonymous function within your container.

```
$this->container['Menu_builder'] = function() {
    // do stuff here

    return function($parameter_1, $parameter_2) {
        return new Menu_builder($parameter_1, $parameter_2);
    };
};
```

Use this way:

```
$localfunc = $this->container['Menu_builder'];
$result = $localfunc($parameter_1, $parameter_2);
```

Notice that in this case I'm not using a factory. That's because you can execute the anonymous function with different values each time.